# Manually deriving the type `(.) (foldr(++)) (map (:))`

Tags: haskell, types, ghci, unification

I'm trying to derive the type of `(.) (foldr(++)) (map (:))`

I start by deriving the type of `foldr (++)`

```
foldr :: (a1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1 -> [a1] -> b1
(++)  :: [a2] -> [a2] -> [a2]

a1 ~ [a2]
b1 ~ [a2]
b1 ~ [a2]
```

So

```
foldr (++) :: [a2] -> [[a2]] -> [a2] ~ [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

Then I derive the type of `map (:)`

```
map :: (a1 -> b1) -> [a1] -> [b1]
(:) :: a2 -> [a2] -> [a2]

a1 ~ a2
b1 ~ [a2] -> [a2]
```

So

```
map (:) :: [a2] -> [[a2] -> [a2]] ~ [a] -> [[a] -> [a]]
```

Finally the type of `(.) (foldr(++)) (map (:))`

```
(.) :: (b1 -> c1) -> (a1 -> b1) -> a1 -> c1
map (:) :: [a2] -> [[a2] -> [a2]]
foldr (++) :: [a3] -> [[a3]] -> [a3]

b1 ~ [a2]
c1 ~ [[a2] -> [a2]]
a1 ~ [a3]
b1 ~ [[a3]] -> [a3]
```

So I get

```
(.) (foldr(++)) (map (:)) :: a1 -> c1 ~ [a3] ->  [[a2] -> [a2]]
```

But if I ask GHCi for `:t (.) (foldr(++)) (map (:))` I get `(.) (foldr(++)) (map (:)) :: [a] -> [[[a] -> [a]]] -> [[a] -> [a]]`

Which is different from my result, any help to derive the same result?

Thanks,
Sebastián.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the final step, you mix up the argument oder. You unify `b1 -> c1` with the type of `map (:)`, but you should unify it with the type of `foldr (++)`.

**More generally**, you might want to learn how to debug such complicated calculations yourself. It is good that you do a sanity check at the end (in this case, by checking the result with ghci). If the sanity check doesn't work, a good next step can be to say or write down what each step is and why you did it. In this case, you would say "and then I unify `b1 -> c1` with the type of `map (:)` because ...", and there you would find the bug because there's no reason to do this.

Maybe [rubber duck debugging](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194922/how-useful-is-rubber-duck-debugging) works for you, where you explain your code to a rubber duck and by explaining, you see what's wrong about the code. .

Answer (score 3):

I’m not quite sure, but I think you missed the fact that you generated two constraints for your `b1`, because in the composition `f . g` the output of `g` has to match the input of `f`. It can be easier to infer the type of a composition by starting from that fact, *then* substituting the inputs and outputs:

```
map (:)              :: [a] -> [[a] -> [a]]
foldr (++)           ::        [b         ] -> [[b         ]] -> [b         ]

[b] ~ [[a] -> [a]]
 b  ~  [a] -> [a]

foldr (++) . map (:) :: [a]                 -> [[b         ]] -> [b         ]
                      ~ [a]                 -> [[[a] -> [a]]] -> [[a] -> [a]]
```